Subdividing microcanonical phase space
If I have a system that I divide into identical halves and compute the density of states for each half, what is the relationship between the total density of states and each half density of states?
Can anything be said generally?

The entropy is the log of the  number of state at energy $E$, which is close to the density of state times a small energy band $S=k_b\log(\Omega_E)=k_b\log(\rho_E\Delta_E)$. With $\rho_E$, the density of state. Since the entropy is extensive, the density of state of a system twice as large should vary more or less as the square of the initial density of state. At least it's exactly true for the number of state.

The total density function is
$$
\rho_{AB}(l_A, l_B) = \rho_A(l_A) \rho_B(l_B)
$$
where A and B are the two halves and $l$ is the state. Here I suppose the two halves are indipendent. If the two halves are identical, the two density functions are the same function.
